# Project compilation with aspectj using ant script on java 1.8 is getting failed with an internal compiler error

Tags: java-8, ant, aspectj

One java project in our application is being compiled with aspectj compiler using ant scripts. It has an .aj file. When we compiled on java 1.8 with aspectj 1.8.x following exception was reported.

```
Internal compiler error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
  at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.MethodVerifier.checkForRedundantSuperinterfaces(MethodVerifier.java:320)

[iajc] abort ABORT -- (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) 1
```

What is the difference between compiling with javac and with aspectj?

Can we compile the project containing .aj files with javac instead of aspectj?

Is aspectj super set of javac or is it other way round?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please understand that this is a Q/A platform about software development. Questions should contain the code that you have problems with. In this case, the Ant script would also help. If nobody can reproduce your problem, nobody can help you either. So please condense your project into the smallest possible size which still reproduces the problem. This is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As for your other question, the AspectJ language (native syntax, not talking about annotation-based syntax here) is a super set of Java. Therefore, the AspectJ Compiler AJC can be used as a full replacement of Javac, but not the other way around. Technically, AJC it is derived from ECJ (Eclipse Java Compiler).

Comment: Please be kind enough to provide some feedback to the people who are trying to help you. Saying nothing is simply not very polite.